# Is it possible for it to be good to do evil? Evil to do good?

Tags: epistemology, good-and-evil

Take for instance you are able to go back in time and have one of the worst leaders in history killed him/ her before they came into power, thus eliminating the atrocities they committed. Or see atrocities being committed, kill them to stop them. The fact that you did this evil thing (killing) becomes a good thing.

On the other hand can something be so overwhelmingly good/ perfect, but implemented or enacted in such a way that it is evil?

At day's end are these labels of good and evil just manifestations of our own viewpoint? How do we know the difference?

Comment: "*I am part of that power which eternally wills evil and eternally works good*”, Mephistopheles from Goethe's Faust.

Comment: @Conifold I remember Faust!

Comment: The issue was explored at length by theologians in the context of theodicy, justification of divine goodness in the face of evil in the world https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy see also Schelling's take, who characterizes the capacity to do evil as the essence of human freedom (which is a good) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Inquiries_into_the_Essence_of_Human_Freedom

Comment: @Conifold I'm trying to avoid the issue(s) surrounding theology, and stick strictly to philosophical viewpoints.

Comment: There are too many frameworks for defining what evil is, to have a settled answer. Discussed here 'Does philosophy have a dark side?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/does-philosophy-have-a-dark-side/89227#89227 Evil as a special category requiring justification, explicitly comes from the religious tradition of theodicy & thinking about free will. I don't think that can be ignored in this context. In say Daoism, there just is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Thats what they call greater good.

If you inject your child with some antidote then the action of putting a needle inside a child (hurting them, altough nowadays they don't hurt as much) is evil. But you do the evil deed for a greater good. To make sure he won't die. In this case you used evil to do good.

The way around is also possible. If your child wants a polar bear as pet. You can give him a polar bear (good deed). But we all know the bear will probably at some point of it's life eat your child (or you :)). And since you know this, and that your child is still unable to reasonably think, it is an evil deed.