# Are there models that seeks to explain and predict ethical phenomenons?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science

Are there models that seeks to explain and predict ethical phenomenons? By models, I mean something like a scientific model. Is there anything like that or did we choose to not use any mathematical constructs to model ethics?

Comment: Do you consider consequentialist's utility model as scientific model? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility)

Comment: I'm confused by the wording.  What do you mean by an ethical phenomenon?  What do you mean by predicting it?  Do you mean a model for evaluating new and unexpected situations to decide the ethical thing to do?  If so, all ethical models I know of can be extrapolated from.

Comment: Sounds like you want game-theory applied to ethics https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/game-ethics/ I discussed a game-theory argument on the ethics of tyrannicide here https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78788/is-the-tyrannicide-perpetrated-by-william-tell-morally-legitimate/78853#78853

Comment: game theory. Read "Liars and Outliers: Enabling the Trust that Society Needs to Thrive" by Bruce Schneier