Sam Harris' Moral Landscape objection
I know that Harris' book, "The Moral Landscape"  has been widely criticized by philosophers. And after listening to him talk with Alex O'Connor relatively recently here, I came to feel that Harris really isn't saying anything new at all. His claim of well-being objectively being an experience a person can subjectively have seems almost indisputable. Are the following critiques valid objections to his "moral landscape" being an objective framework of ethics?
Harris claims that there is a landscape of possible choices of action that will result in various values of well-being in a person. His axiom (though he often disagrees with the fact that he is defining a specific ethical framework) is that we must maximize well-being of people; we must find "peaks" in the moral landscape, as he describes. An immediate objection appears to me: whose well-being are you maximizing? Any action will generally affect different peoples well-being in a different direction or magnitude. Thus each person has an individual "well-being function". And it is meaningless to find a point that simultaneously optimizes a general set of functions; one can easily construct a set functions in which a maximum of one is a minimum of another. If Harris attempts to combine all individual well-being functions into a "universal well-being function", does he just arrive at a form of Utilitarianism? At which a very simple and extreme counter-example is available. Suppose we were capable of torturing one infant for all of eternity, and doing so would grant extreme well-being to everyone else alive or to be born. Torturing the infant would definitely be a peak on the moral landscape; the extreme well-being of everyone would far outweigh the suffering of a single infant. But that is intuitively incorrect.
Furthermore, the idea of even having a correct "universal well-being function" also seems meaningless. It's meaningless to even calculate a mean across everyone's well-being because peoples subjective experiences of well-being cannot be compared to each other without defining some sort of value to each individual's experience. I would say it is even meaningless to assign real numbers to each person's subjective experience in any modal scenario; I don't believe well-being can be ordered. Even if it could, two peoples' "5.0 well-being" are different subjective experiences. And any function that translates one persons 5.0 to another persons 5.0 would once again be assigning value to different people.
If we do not compare "well-being functions" and simply optimize our own well-being, we just get Egoism correct?
Even if there is a neurological way to objectively assign a real number to a persons subjective experience, we still have the problem of which function we optimize.

(Counter-arguments such as those against utilitarianism tend to fail when one considers the negative utility of permitting the violation of people's autonomy or the intentional infliction of suffering on them, and the resulting distress in the rest of society from being aware of that being permitted, if not in practice, then at least in theory, and when one considers the much more fundamental problems with competing moral frameworks, and when one considers that many such examples are extremely far removed from anything that could reasonably be expected to happen.)

Either Sam Harris is clueless. Or you've misplaced your moral compass

Do you have video link to the discussion betwixt Connor & Harris?

The claim that there is some identifiable objective experience of "well-being" is not only disputable but very plausibly false. The word refers to different sentiments in different circumstances, and grouping those together relies on subjective judgments of what counts. But your objection is valid too. There is nothing objective about picking one particular kind of sentiment, like "well-being", as morally controlling even if we could objectively pin it down. People can pick, say, piety instead, and if it conflicts with "well-being" then so much the worse for the "well-being".

Maybe we should define well-being, so that we could then use it to determine things? Everyone agrees that there should be a definition, so get it figured out.

In my view Sam wants to embed the ethics of Buddhist compassion into modern secular public policy. Public servants and the population would have to transform for that to happen. Experts are trying to embed typical human value-of-life decisions into algorithms for operating autonomous vehicles. This is similar to Sam's claim that values can be explicit in a logical or topographical map. I, Robot (2004) SPOILER ALERT! Sonny is a robot with human emotional intelligence who learns rapidly. VIKI is logical, paternalistic, and thinks robots should curb human liberty to maximize our well-being.

You can avoid the need to numerically evaluate well-being by using something like Maslow's pyramid scheme. People move from one level to the next as their needs are filled (or start going unfilled). There is an upward direction, and each person can pretty much say where they are by what needs are filled and unfilled. You don't need to compare people, just help them go up the levels. Up is good! Down is bad! (see how that works?)

I have to admit I've alwaysbeen pretty biased against Harris. But I've been listening to the podcast link for a while and am pleasantly surprised by most of what he says (though I don't agree with everything). I think the question here is trivializing/oversimplifiying what he is saying and is not giving a reliable summary.

Harris is a little clueless, but I don't see any particular problem with using a metaphor to visualize the concept of local maxima on an n+1 dimensional hypersurface to whatever extent the n dimensions have distinguishable coordinates and to whatever extent the 1 dimension has some level of quantifiability.

@ScottRowe - I took a course on Buddhist ethics with a local Zen group. I quoted a Zen master (Questions to a Zen Master) who said, Karma is thought, speech, and action. My friend the Zen master says, "Are you sure that's all there is to it?" I reread the materials he provided for the course where the author claims that human intention is the dominant factor in our psychological experience.  In the context of Maslow's hierarchy of needs we need to interact with parents and parent-like folks who are prudent (with the ability to govern action by the use of reason) and have good intentions.

I believe Sam Harris' mistake is a kind of begging the question; what is at issue in discussions about value are if value exists and what kind of existence value(s) has, if any. It seems to me that Harris assumes that well-being is what is exclusively valuable, which is not an uncontroversial position (e.g. this SEP page on well-being goes through some challenges to this view).
If we take it as given that well-being is what is valuable then, even if we do not think we are obligated to maximize everyone's well-being, we are committed to the view that it is in fact better for overall well-being to be higher. That is, we might not be compelled to maximize well-being even if it is in fact better for well-being to be improved.
If it is not well-being per se that is valuable but one's own particular well-being I think you can avoid the entailment that higher overall well-being is better (independent of moral obligations to pursue that higher well-being). Such a view comes with its own difficulties, though, as an argument would need to be made that there is something special about the fact that any particular constituent experience of well-being is "one's own" that makes that well-being valuable but that fails to obtain for others.
Though the baby thought experiment you raise might seem to be an unacceptable trade-off, I think utilitarians of various sorts would bite the bullet and affirm that in such a hypothetical it would be better overall to torture the baby. However, utilitarians could counter that the world in which that thought experiment is possible is one very far from our own and so the unintuitiveness of that commitment should not be too worrying.
Regarding potential egoism, it could be that each individual is generally in a uniquely good epistemic position to assess their own well-being and so pursuing that is actually good for others inasmuch as many of the things that can help well-being require cooperating with others (community, kinship, love, and nowadays a specialized market economy pushing the technological envelope).

The problem of one suffering child versus the happiness of all the rest was first described in Dostoievsky's Brother Karamazov (if you have not read that yet, you'd might enjoy reading it). I don't think utilitarians can (or will) shrug it off since it seems essentially the same problem as the Trolley Problem -- which is also a very real problem in AI (for self-driving cars and other autonomous agents for instance).

@mudskipper People working in AI often roll their eyes at the contrived trolley problems which tend to get trotted out. "Should you steer toward the cliff or the group of orphans?" is met with "Neither: you should brake quickly and heavily, and rather than spending your time teaching the AI moral philosophy, you should spend it updating the sensors and the path prediction algorithms such that you never get into such no-win situations to begin with." (Which is effectively countering that the real world is different from the thought experiment one.)

@R.M. - Yeah - I can see that. Still there might be situations where the choice is: either those two pedestrians (or the little puppy crossing the street) will croak, or the driver will end up in the water... We're forced to either simplify the moral calculus or to accept that moral reasoning breaks down.

@ElliFo - I don't think Harris is using "well-being" as a substantive term. He explicitly says he is using it as a kind of "suitcase" term, leaving open a substantive definition.

Personally I think the specific thought experiment mentioned is a relatively small bullet to bite (I'm willing to bite far larger ones with regard to consequentialism), which is anecdata but though I don't think consequentialists shrug off such thought experiments but have various ways of responding, one of which is that any ethical theory generates unintuitive consequences and choosing one over another means accepting certain unintuitive consequences over other ones. re: Harris' use of well-being, though he might not offer a substantive definition I don't think he uses the term as a suitcase

continued... as a suitcase admitting of holding any substantive definition, but uses the term well-being specifically because of certain limits that places on the value he identifies, though I could be wrong! also, I read the brothers a while ago, but should do so again! @mudskipper

@ElliFo - I do agree that Harris sets the bar rather low: In a perfect hell "you'll be disposed, as a conscious mind, to move away from that pointless misery". I also don't think that that concept is coherent. A hell in which one would not be so disposed seems to me worse, for instance. (Or a hell in which you'd be disposed, but are not able to. There are countless variations to make.) I don't think he limits the content of "the good" ("well-being") - that's explicitly left up to "everyone", "us". The problem I think is there literally is no clear "us" (or "I") - unless as idealization.

Even the hand-on-the-stove example is not really convincing -- in this regard -- because it assumes particular subjects and abilities (ignoring that some people cannot feel physical pain); it also ignores that pain is a useful signal, it's not "pure, infinite evil" (if that's a coherent notion); it ignores pain as actual process (at some point the subject will pass out or die). It seems that philosophers never actually listen to what they themselves are saying.

In Moral Landscape, Harris set out to breach the is/ought barrier.  He argues that morality is a natural fact, and can be studied as a field of science.
This is an interesting premise.  It is not obviously wrong.  But unfortunately it was not well served by Harris's mismanagement of the discussion.
IF one wants to breach the is/ought barrier, AND wants to use science to do so, THEN there are two things one must do:

Identify inescapably real phenomenon one can use as the basis of this moral science
Demonstrate, with science data, that a science-based method provides the greatest utility and understanding in interpreting this data in moral terms.

Harris fails at both tasks.
What Harris starts with is welfare, which is a nice improvement on early utilitarianism, which focussed on the more basic but far less important pleasure/pain.  BUT Harris limits himself to a neurologic reductionist framework, and welfare/harm is not even translatable in the terms he limits himself to.  Harm and welfare are emergent concepts, not reductionist ones, and are not localized in time, nor can they be characterized neurologically.  If Harris wanted to work just with pleasure/pain, he would at least have some neural analogs to point to.  But WELFARE?  HARM?  He misses out on the first bullet above.
THEN, Harris provides NO rationale for his choice of a welfare/harm utilitarianism.  Instead, he repeatedly asks a rhetorical question "what other alternative is there"?  WELLLLL ... anyone even moderately versed in ethical theorizing, could identify a dozen!  Just take a freshman level intro to philosophy, and at least a half dozen will be discussed!
Any actual "scientist" would have identified the alternate hypotheses that others have proposed (pleasure/pain utility, rights ethics, harm minimization, darwinian law of tooth and claw, eusociality, virtue ethics, teleological ethics, clean hands, deep ecology, etc), then would have proposed goodness metrics to evaluate between them, then would have cited experimental evidence that shows the preferability of his approach over his rivals.  Yet Harris, despite being a vocal advocate for scientism, does not seem to actually understand what science consists of, and fails to do any of these steps.
I consider this failing of Harris's to be characteristic of the advocates of scientism, who are often as woefully unaware of what good science consists of as Harris appears to be.  His use of rhetorical sleight of hand, rather than science, in his argument for scientizing morality, serves as a thorough condemnation of his project.
Along the way, he commits several other absurdities.  He argues that the uniqueness of consciousness is what makes humans particularly morally valuable.  BUT -- very many animals are almost certainty conscious, yet he does not address animal welfare/rights at all.
Also, he cites the need for non-scientists to accept science consensus, basically because civilians cannot understand the details of how an experiment is done well or badly and data analyzed.  Then he advocates for NEUROSCIENTISTS to therefore be our moral theorists, and named several philosophers too as among the expert community who should do our moral thinking, in Daniel Dennett and the Churchland's.  Philosophers DO do pretty complex thinking, but few understand neuroscience to the point of expertise, and neither Dennett nor the Churchland's likely qualify.  But of particular note, is that the Churchland's are eliminative materialists about consciousness, and Dennett is the leading Delusionist about consciousness.  Their views lead them to DENY the phenomenon he is using to even make a moral argument -- hence per his own thinking, they CANNOT be experts on morality, because they deny its object.
For a review making these points, see: https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3SB3ZQ7Y8SX1Y?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp
How to do this right, rather than how Harris did it?
Start with admitting that most subjects are not actually sciences.  Moral thinking is -- a branch of philosophy.  It can and should be informed by evidence, but scientific studies are not going to be sufficiently clear and definitive to settle moral questions.
Then abandon a narrow ontology.  DON'T rely upon materialism, dualism, or neutral monism to derive a valid morality.  Our world's ontology is an open question, so don't lock the answer into a very likely wrong assumption.
Treat our moral intuitions as actual sense data about the world, but colored by our cultural upbringing. Some moral thinking is enmeshed with a culture's prejudices.   But others, can be seen as moral across cultures.  Look for the cross-cultural moral commonality, and treat those intuitions as sense data about the reality of morality.
We have three widely respected moral frameworks cross-culturally.  Utilitairnaism, rights ethics, and love/truth virtue ethics.  There are two others that I add to these three, to make a collection of moral thinking tools:  Eusociality, and Deep Ecology.  Use these 5 cross-cultural tools to do a moral evaluation.  If they all agree, then you know what is moral!  If 3/5 agree, and the two outliers are in regions of decision space they do poorly in, once more you know what is moral!
For an example of how to do this, see:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/78826/29339

I didn't read the book - only listened to the podcast. Harris's talk about consciousness did strike me as "off" and as pretty irrelevant. Surely, it's sentience that matters, not consciousness. -- Can you provide a good link for "eusociality"? I'm not familiar with that as a separate theory.

Eusociality is the term used to describe communal animals, that behave as a hive rather than as individuals.  Ants and bees are the premier examples.  Multicellular creatures are likewise eusocial with respect to cells.  E.O Wilson studied them for decades, then expanded the term, to argue that there are degrees of  Eusociality, and we humans are at the lowest rung, because we care for each other's young, and for each other when injured.

Eusocial species are over represented among the most successful animals. A Eusociality advocate would note that most of morality has to do with suppressing our selfishness for community good.  A study of humans would also reveal that we use ideological thinking, moralizing, and us/them categories to defend our tribal tribe/community and reject rival tribe/communities, so evolutional and human eusociality have twisted our moral sense for the benefit of the "community" not us. Kate Disten's question in the Selfish Meme "do you run your memes, or do they run you" applies to eusocial thinking too.

@mudskipper forgot to at.

You're saying I think, that Harris skipped some steps by choosing harm / welfare and going from that point. You say there are a dozen alternatives that can be evaluated. But I think we don't always have to start by surveying the field and ranking all the possibilities. The Wright Brothers focused on powered flight. Were there alternatives, like balloons, submarines, hovercraft, teleportation... Yes. But powered flight would be the killer app (barring teleportation, which still is not being investigated). They went forth in one direction and got it done. Maybe harm / welfare will work?

@ScottRowe Utilitarian calculus around harm/welfare is particularly hard to CALCULATE, but if one just squints and approximates, it is not a bad ethical system.  It is not great when you are the unlucky patient in for a minor surgery, whose organs happen to be what is needed by a dozen other simultaneous patients ....  In some cases, rights ethics is far superior. In others, welfare is less important than character/growth.  In yet others, it really is the community, or the planet, we should be thinking about, not individuals.  I like Utilitarian harm/welfare 2nd best of my collection.

We have to start somewhere, with something people can understand and agree on. We can improve it after the building is not on fire anymore. 2nd best is still ok, eh?

@Dcleve (AFAIK) the utilitarian consensus is that killing people for their organs is not okay, for the utilitarian reason that society delivers huge value due to being the kind of place where people aren't randomly murdered and their organs divvied up.

@piojo -- So people think that pure utility is a bad enough moral theory in enough cases, that this rejection of utility theory in favor of rights theory in some cases is part of our utility summing?  How about Virtues cases?  And I note you summed on society, not individuals, so eusocial overlays on individual metric? Also animal welfare?  And Deep Ecology?  The Utilitarian calculus was already impossible to perform when it was just pleasure/pain, it became impossible in principle with welfare/harm.  Thinking one can also embed 5 other moral theories within it in a sum is silly. Go pluralist.


Harris claims that there is a landscape of possible choices of action
that will result in various values of well-being in a person. His
axiom (though he often disagrees with the fact that he is defining a
specific ethical framework) is that we must maximize well-being of
people; we must find "peaks" in the moral landscape, as he describes.
An immediate objection appears to me: whose well-being are you
maximizing? Any action will generally affect different peoples
well-being in a different direction or magnitude. Thus each person has
an individual "well-being function". And it is meaningless to find a
point that simultaneously optimizes a general set of functions; one
can easily construct a set functions in which a maximum of one is a
minimum of another. If Harris attempts to combine all individual
well-being functions into a "universal well-being function", does he
just arrive at a form of Utilitarianism?

If you read his book, Harris deliberately refrains from defining a function.
One of the key arguments the book tries to make is that, much like medical science is preoccupied with studying the effect of real-world problems on human health to improve it in general (without defining a specific global health function), a science of ethics should similarly study the effect of real-world problems on human well-being to improve it in general.
Even medical science works with trade-offs, and it leaves the judgment of those trade-offs to health professionals and patients themselves. A drug is not going to make you +X healthier, but rather have a range of positive effects as well as a number of potential side-effects, and there's no single global function to evaluate those.
Harris seems to be pushing for studying the positive and negative impact of actions and policies on well-being in general and doesn't seem too concerned with finding a global utilitarian well-being function.  While "the moral landscape" is a theoretical visualization of such a function, it's used simply to illustrate the point that well-being is worth optimizing and can be optimized.

At which a very simple and extreme counter-example is the available.
Suppose we were capable of torturing one infant for all of eternity,
and doing so would grant extreme well-being to everyone else alive or
to be born. Torturing the infant would definitely be a peak on the
moral landscape; the extreme well-being of everyone would far outweigh
the suffering of a single infant. But that is intuitively incorrect.

Just to comment on this counter-example — you're assuming here that the universal well-being function would be additive. It could very well not be. If it was, say, multiplicative, a zero well-being value for the infant would make the global well-being function equal zero as well, regardless of how high the well-being of others would be.

Furthermore, the idea of even having a correct "universal well-being
function" also seems meaningless. Its meaningless to even calculate a
mean across everyone's well-being because peoples subjective
experiences of well-being cannot be compared to each other without
defining some sort of value to each individual's experience. I would
say it is even meaningless to assign real numbers to each person's
subjective experience in any modal scenario; I don't believe
well-being can be ordered. Even if it could, two peoples' "5.0
well-being" are different subjective experiences. And any function
that translates one persons 5.0 to another persons 5.0 would once
again be assigning value to different people.
If we do not compare "well-being functions" and simply optimize our
own well-being, we just get Egoism correct?
Even if there is a neurological way to objectively assign a real
number to a persons subjective experience, we still have the problem
of which function do we optimize.

The fact that there isn't a clear-cut way to design a universal well-being function does not mean that well-being cannot be optimized.
Perhaps the set of well-being outcomes is not a totally ordered set, but rather a partially ordered set (where only some elements can be compared). Having a cold or being yelled at by a stranger might not be directly comparable, but in either case, your well-being would likely be better without either of those things. And there are a large number of cases that can be similarly evaluated even without a specific global function.

We do not have to assume any kind of quantititave function here. It's much more fruitful to mathematically model this in a non-quantititative way, for instance as done by Nigel Howard, "Paradoxes of Rationality - Theory of Metagames and Political Behavior" (1971). This whole discussion about a "well-being functions" and it's purported difficulties is completely resolvable in a non-quantitative theory (resolvable up to the fact that people may have conflicting preference orderings). The theoretically interesting question here is merely what are the minimal assumptions (axioms) needed...
