# Question on Simone de Beauvoir's ”The Second Sex”

Tags: ethics, feminism, sexism

Could someone help break down this section from ”The Second Sex” by Beauvoir?

“Indeed, along with the ethical urge of each individual to affirm his subjective existence, there is also the temptation to forgo liberty and become a thing. This is an inauspicious road, for he who takes it – passive, lost, ruined – becomes henceforth the creature of another’s will, frustrated in his transcendence and deprived of every value. But it is an easy road; on it one avoids the strain involved in undertaking an authentic existence.”

Also is that excerpt referencing some other work of hers where she covers that concept in more detail?

Comment: Presumably the passage is about where one places self-value -- in *being* (perhaps one's body alone) or in *doing* (one's autonomy).

Comment: See recent duplicate: 'Evil Force in The Second Sex mentioned by Simone de Beauvoir' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87076/evil-force-in-the-second-sex-mentioned-by-simone-de-beauvoir/87079#87079

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evil Force in The Second Sex mentioned by Simone de Beauvoir](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87076/evil-force-in-the-second-sex-mentioned-by-simone-de-beauvoir)